# Log messages from two modules to different files and include logging from modules that use other logging facilities

Tags: python, logging

I have a script that imports two modules - `mailserver.py` and `client.py`. Each of these has a method, similar to:

```
def startLogger(logPath):
    log.discardLogs()
    d = os.path.dirname(logPath)
    if not os.path.exists(d):
        os.makedirs(d)
    log.startLogging(open(logPath, 'a'))
```

Then I call the function with a different parameter from `mailserver.py` and `client.py` but they end up overwriting each other's settings (so the last invocation wins).

Obviously, I could use multiple loggers as per the [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html). What prevents me from that is

- various downstream scripts / modules use a few other logging facilities (e.g. Twisted and `smtplib`'s internal facility)
- some facilities can only use a "default" destination

So I guess these log entries would be lost unless I create an extensive set of overriding code.

The question is: what is the best practice to set up two logging destinations for  `mailserver.py` and `client.py` and all their respective dependent modules?

Comment: Rewritten to make it comprehensible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not overcomplicate things. Use a single logging facility whenever possible.

A sane logging facility (including `logging`) doesn't require each module to specify log locations and such - they only need to be specified in some one dedicated place (e.g. in the main module).

So use one. For `logging`, in imported modules, this is be as easy as

```
l=logging.getLogger('<distinguishing name>')
#use l's methods
```

If you wanna log with both `logging` and `twisted`, it's best to write a `logging` `Handler` that would replicate messages to Twisted.

### Example: adapting foreign facilities

In one of my past projects (an SMTP proxy that uses `smtplib` and `smtpd`), this is
how I weaved various logging facilities together under `logging`:

```
import logging    
l = logging.getLogger() #root logger to be used in the main module
f = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(process)d:%(thread)d %(name)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
<set log file, install an excepthook to log unhandled exceptions>
class LogStream(smtpd.Devnull):
    """A write-only stream-like interface to logging module.
    write() and flush() are the public interface"""
    def __init__(self,name=None,level=logging.DEBUG):
    def write(self,s):
        """log the data, line-buffered; uses flush() with argument internally"""
    def flush(self,p=None):
        """log and remove `p' (default - all) bytes from the buffer.
        The `p' parameter is not a part of the public interface"""

class asyncore_logger:
    <some settings>
    @classmethod
    def log(cls,msg,level='info'):
        """A compatible replacement for asyncore.dispatcher.log_info.
        The class is only needed as a settings container"""

smtpd.DEBUGSTREAM=LogStream('smtpd')
#smtpd logs receipts but not replies
smtpd.SMTPChannel.push=<custom_wrapper_using_DEBUGSTREAM>(smtpd.SMTPChannel.push)
smtplib.stderr=LogStream('smtplib')
asyncore.dispatcher.log_info = asyncore_logger.log
#clean up entries that are no longer needed in the local namespace
del LogStream, asyncore_logger, <custom_wrapper_using_DEBUGSTREAM>
```

With this, I have a single log file with messages from my program, `smtplib`, `smtpd` and `asyncore`, labelled appropriately (the `%(name)s` field).

### Logging to multiple files with `logging`

Create multiple `Handler`s and attach `Filter`s to those who need to only include specific messages. To distinguish by the source library, you'll probably be filtering by `name`.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't explain to me (at least I don't think so) of how I can get all server log messages (including libraries used by the server script) to one location, and all client log messages (including libraries used by the client script) to another location.

Also, we may well need to include logging facility definition in each of the server and client code, since we may want to start one without the other....

Comment: You didn't specify which module uses which facility so I cannot say anything more specific. I can only give an example how I used to do it.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks @ivan_pozdeev - Think I get it! I'll give it a go! :)